Difference in behavior of Storage::get() between Laravel 7 and Laravel 9 regarding file not found exception
I'm experiencing different behaviors in Laravel 7 and Laravel 9 regarding the Storage::get() method when the file does not exist. In Laravel 7, it throws a FileNotFoundException exception, while in Laravel 9, it returns null.
I'm curious about the reasons behind these changes. Why does Laravel 7 throw an exception while Laravel 9 returns null? Additionally, when I try to trace the implementation using XDebug, I find that the code interception is not occurring in the underlying filesystem.php.
Could someone provide insights into why this difference in behavior exists between Laravel 7 and Laravel 9, and why the interception is not happening as expected?
Code snippet (simplified):
<?php
// Laravel 7 behavior
try {
    $content = Storage::get('nonexistent-file.txt');
    // This block will not be executed if the file does not exist
    echo $content;
} catch (\Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException $e) {
    // Handle the file not found exception
    echo "File not found: " . $e->getMessage();
}

// Laravel 9 behavior
$content = Storage::get('nonexistent-file.txt');
if ($content === null) {
    // Handle the case when the file does not exist
    echo "File not found";
}


In filesystems.php add throw => true to filesystem config. And check upgrade manual :)

This change is documented in the Upgrade Guide going from Laravel 8.x to 9.x: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade#flysystem-3
Laravel upgraded Flysystem from 1.x to 3.x which changed a lot of things related to file system manipulation. Check the upgrade guide for all (breaking) changes.
